# iphone: what should I learn?

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c

I'm a total noob working in basics of C++ right now; I enjoy it, but find myself wondering if I'm not (sort of) wasting my time learning something archaic that won't be applicable to my interest in programming for iphone/ipad.

Should I be starting out with Obj-C, or will I be able to write better programs/ have more perspective if I continue learning C++?

I am a patient man. But I also want to be investing my time wisely.

Thanks!
-Andrew

Answer (score 2):

C++ and Objective C are not as closely related as either C and Obj-C or C and C++. Frankly, just start with Objective C if you know you want to do iPhone or Mac programming. Second most important is the corresponding libraries, Cocoa (for mac) or Cocoa-touch (for iphone). Knowing the language isn't enough to get you productive in the platform.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with starting with objective-C. From personal experience I recommed it. I learned to program in objective-C before any other language and now I've made/worked on some very successful applications. As you become a better objective-C programmer you will naturally become better at programming overall, and C++ will be easy to pick up along the way if it's ever needed. The resources for objective-C and iPhone are vast and the language is fun to learn. If you need recommendations for good objective-C resources ask.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to iOS, you could start by learning C and then go to Obj-C or just start at Obj-C.

Answer (score 1):

Learn obj-c. That's what you are going to use to program.  Its always fun to think you'll gain a deep knowledge by learning a low lvl lang.  Once you get into building iPhone apps, you'll find the debugging skills you need and use are more high level.

Answer (score 0):

Just learn Obj-C.  It's similar to C++ in the OOP features it implements, but the syntax is quite different.  Also, it's good to that you're a patient guy, patience is massively important.  I can't stress enough to start slow and make sure you learn Obj-C inside and out in addition to Cocoa before jumping into something as big as iPhone deving, or you'll burn out in frustration.  In addition to Cocos-2D, be sure to check out [71 Squared](http://www.71squared.com/).  It's a great resource.